# Using static c++ getter instead of simply accessing variable causes SIGSEGV ndk

Tags: c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I encountered a very strange runtime error:
I have following class

```
class Application {
public:
  Application(){}
  Application(Window* w)
  :window(w)
  {};

  static std::string const& getDataStorageDirectory(){
      return dataStorageDir;
  }

  static std::string dataStorageDir;
  Window* window;
};
```

and in Application.cpp I initialize it:
`std::string Application::dataStorageDir="asd";`

Now, I am using opengles/ndk in a "standard" way (own Activity and own GLSurfaceView.Renderer (it is running another thread).

Now if I use in my code:
`LOGI("data storage: %s", Application::dataStorageDir.c_str());`
then it works nicely, but if i use:
`std::string p = Application::getDataStorageDirectory();
LOGI("data storage (renderer): %s", p.c_str());`
then it ends with a SIGSEGV

What may be causing this problem?

Comment: Just to make sure - the only difference between your two attempts is this line of getting the string? Also, is the crash on the line of the LOGI?

Comment: Yes, this is the only difference.

Comment: Another, maybe better example: http://pastebin.com/vbeKtY3v

Comment: And the crash was on Application::getDataStorageDirectory();

Comment: Ok, it happened probably beceause I am calling this codes from one of my constructors. Will dig this topic more